# IE6 dropdown Navigation not working

Tags: internet-explorer-6, navigation

My dropdown menu is not working in IE6. Here is the css code

```
 a:focus {
outline:none;}

.menu {
width:1000px; 
height:32px; 
position:relative; 
z-index:100;
font-family:arial, sans-serif;
}

/* hack to correct IE5.5 faulty box model */
* html .menu {
width:1000px; 

}

/* remove all the bullets, borders and padding from the default list styling */
.menu ul {
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
}

.menu ul ul {
width:149px;
}

/* float the list to make it horizontal and a relative positon so that you can control the dropdown menu positon */
.menu li {
float:left;
width:149px;
position:relative; 
border-top: #999 1px solid;
 margin-right:10px;
 }

.menu li:hover {
float:left;
border-top: #ff0 1px solid;
}

.nav-selected {
font-weight: bold;
}

.menu li li:hover {
float:left;
border-top: none;
 color: #999;
 }

.menu li li {
float:left; 
width:149px; 
position:relative; 
border-top: none;
}


/* style the links for the top level */
.menu a, .menu a:visited {
display:block;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration:none; 
color:#999; 
width:149px; 
height:26px; 
line-height:29px;
}

/* a hack so that IE5.5 faulty box model is corrected */
* html .menu a, * html .menu a:visited {
width:149px; 
w\idth:149px;
}

/* style the second level background */
.menu ul ul a.drop, .menu ul ul a.drop:visited {}
/* style the second level hover */
.menu ul ul a.drop:hover{}
.menu ul ul :hover > a.drop {}
/* style the third level background */
.menu ul ul ul a, .menu ul ul ul a:visited {}
/* style the third level hover */
.menu ul ul ul a:hover {}

/* hide the sub levels and give them a positon absolute so that they take up no room */
.menu ul ul {

visibility: hidden;
position:absolute;
height:0;
top:26px;
left:0; 
width:150px;

}

/* another hack for IE5.5 */
* html .menu ul ul {
top:26px; 
t\op:27px;
}

/* position the third level flyout menu */
.menu ul ul ul{
left:149px;
 top:-1px; 
 width:149px;
 }

/* position the third level flyout menu for a left flyout */
.menu ul ul ul.left {
left:-149px;
}



/* style the table so that it takes no ppart in the layout - required for IE to work */
.menu table {
position:absolute;
top:0; 
left:0; 
border-collapse:collapse;
}

/* style the second level links */
.menu ul ul a, .menu ul ul a:visited {
color:#999; 
height:auto; 
line-height:15px; 
padding-bottom:4px; 
width:149px;
}

/* yet another hack for IE5.5 */
* html .menu ul ul a, * html .menu ul ul a:visited {
width:149px; 
w\idth:149px;
}

/* style the top level hover */
.menu a:hover {color:#ff0;}
.menu ul ul a:hover {color:#ccc;}
.menu :hover > a {color:#ff0;}
.menu ul ul :hover > a {color:#ccc;}

/* make the second level visible when hover on first level list OR link */
.menu ul li:hover ul, .menu ul a:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
width: auto;
 }
/* keep the third level hidden when you hover on first level list OR link */
.menu ul :hover ul ul{
visibility:hidden;
}
/* make the third level visible when you hover over second level list OR link */
.menu ul :hover ul :hover ul{ 
visibility:visible;
}
```

Please help me as soon as possible...

Comment: Can you show your HTML content?

Comment: Not working in what way? Which browsers?

Comment: @Atomiton At tags and title written ie6 browser ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the actual drop-down portions of the menu not working, it's because the `overflow` command is broken in `IE6`.  `IE6` does not properly display `overflow` properties (in this case `overflow: visible` to allow the dropdown menu to be shown).  Unfortunately there is no easy fix.  You can search on the web for some CSS Hacks for IE6 to try and fix the overflow issue, but they do not work with every case.  Good luck.